# How to strech images to fill page horizontaly?

Tags: java, android, xml

As you can see on the image below, I have 6 horizontal layouts, with 6 image buttons in each, in total 36 image buttons. Every button is 120x123 pixels in xdhpi, 80x92 in hdmi, 53x61 in mdpi folders. On the bottom you can see my whole XML code for this activity. The problem is, I need those bricks to strech all the way hirizontaly. As you can see the layout containing those brick goes all the way, but the images don't. I tried to make the images bigger, 128px in widht but that didn't help at all.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="365dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSlika"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="365dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_01"
            android:padding="0dp" />/

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_02"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_03"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_04"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_05"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_06"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_07"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_08"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_09"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_10"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_11"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_12"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_13"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_14"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_15"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_16"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_17"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_18"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_19"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_20"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_21"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_22"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_23"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_24"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_25"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_26"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_27"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_28"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_29"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_30"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_31"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_32"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_33"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_34"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_35"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bricks_36"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things to remember:

- set the android:layout_width of the children to "0dp"
- set the android:weightSum of the parent (edit: as Jason Moore
  noticed, this attribute is optional, because by default it is set to
  the children's layout_weight sum)
- set the android:layout_weight of each child proportionally (e.g.
  weightSum="5", three children: layout_weight="1", layout_weight="3",
  layout_weight="1")

Example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is almost good solution, but I still get the space between the bricks. How to stretch them?

Comment: Found it. android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton extends ImageView, so scaleType is accessible. That would allow you to control how the image is stretched within the button. fitXY will stretch the image so it fills the entire area of the ImageView (or ImageButton.)

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Answer (score 0):

Add one more attribute in your ImageButton **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** and instaed of 
**android:src="@drawable/img_icon"** use **android:background="@drawable/img_icon"**.

For more info about **android:adjustViewBounds** [Click here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds)